# pyenv error installing Python 3.6.7 or 2.7.8 in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python, versions, openssl

I am trying to install Python 2.7.8 and Python 3.6.7 using Pyenv but I have always the same problem:

```
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 18.04 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20190531162212.22464
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20190531162212.22464.log

Last 10 log lines:
        install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
    esac; \
     ./python -E -m ensurepip \
        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
```

I have tried all the possibilities in the pyenv common problems and changed the OPENSSL version.

Comment: Please add pyenv versions , openssl version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what happened is a path issue between your python version and your pyenv python version.

You must have hardcoded the python version through an alias or something into the .bashrc file.

Just :

- uninstall pyenv
- go into the bashrc file and remove python alias
- install pyenv again

Comment: Thank's! Your recommendation solved my problem for the Python 3.6.7 installation! I still have the same issue for the python 2.7.8 installation, but the major problem ( being able to install a stable version of python 3.6 ) is solved!

Comment: You might wanna stick with python3 if you don't need python2 for a specific reason since python2 is going to be discontinued